# Using :: (scope resolution operator) in C++

Tags: c++, function, namespaces

I am learning C++ and I can never tell when I need to use `::` . I do know that I need to use `std::` in front of `cout` and `cin`. Does this mean that inside of the `iostream` file the developers that created it  made a namespace called `std` and put the functions `cin` and `cout` into the namespace called `std`? When I created a new class that isn't in the same file as `main()` for some reason I must add `::` .

For example, if I create a `class` called `A` , why do I need to put `A::` in front of a function that I make, even though I didn't put it into a namespace? For example `void A::printStuff(){}` . If I create a function in `main`, why don't I have to put `main::printStuff{}` ?

I know that my question is probably confusing, but could someone help me?

Comment: A fine question, but a little too broad (IMO). That's called the scope-resolution operator, and your search term for further learning is *scope*. All those names (`cout`, member functions of `A`) are defined in *scopes* and you have to resolve the scope (that is, tell the compiler where to look) with `::`.

Comment: The prefix to `::` can be either a namespace or a class. Since `main` is neither (it's a function), `main::printStuff` would be incorrect.

Comment: :: gives an idea of ownership also, when a definition is part of a class or of a namespace, you should use :: to access it... not exactly that, but that gives a you a feeling.

Comment: `cout` and `cin` are not functions, they are objects.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You're pretty much right about `cout` and `cin`. They are objects (not functions) defined inside the `std` namespace. Here are their declarations as defined by the C++ standard:

> Header `<iostream>` synopsis
>
> ```
> #include <ios>
> #include <streambuf>
> #include <istream>
> #include <ostream>
>
> namespace std {
>   extern istream cin;
>   extern ostream cout;
>   extern ostream cerr;
>   extern ostream clog;
>
>   extern wistream wcin;
>   extern wostream wcout;
>   extern wostream wcerr;
>   extern wostream wclog;
> }
> ```

`::` is known as the *scope resolution operator*. The names `cout` and `cin` are defined within `std`, so we have to qualify their names with `std::`.

Classes behave a little like namespaces in that the names declared inside the class belong to the class. For example:

```
class foo
{
  public:
    foo();
    void bar();
};
```

The constructor named `foo` is a *member* of the class named `foo`. They have the same name because its the constructor. The function `bar` is also a member of `foo`.

Because they are members of `foo`, when referring to them from outside the class, we have to qualify their names. After all, they belong to that class. So if you're going to define the constructor and `bar` outside the class, you need to do it like so:

```
foo::foo()
{
  // Implement the constructor
}

void foo::bar()
{
  // Implement bar
}
```

This is because they are being defined *outside* the class. If you had not put the `foo::` qualification on the names, you would be defining some new functions in the global scope, rather than as members of `foo`. For example, this is entirely different `bar`:

```
void bar()
{
  // Implement different bar
}
```

It's allowed to have the same name as the function in the `foo` class because it's in a different scope. This `bar` is in the global scope, whereas the other `bar` belonged to the `foo` class.

Answer (score 35):

The `::` are used to dereference scopes.

```
const int x = 5;

namespace foo {
  const int x = 0;
}

int bar() {
  int x = 1;
  return x;
}

struct Meh {
  static const int x = 2;
}

int main() {
  std::cout << x; // => 5
  {
    int x = 4;
    std::cout << x; // => 4
    std::cout << ::x; // => 5, this one looks for x outside the current scope
  }
  std::cout << Meh::x; // => 2, use the definition of x inside the scope of Meh
  std::cout << foo::x; // => 0, use the definition of x inside foo
  std::cout << bar(); // => 1, use the definition of x inside bar (returned by bar)
}
```

unrelated:
cout and cin are not functions, but instances of stream objects.

Answer (score 33):

The `::` is called scope resolution operator. 
Can be used like this:

`::` *identifier*
*class-name* `::` *identifier*
*namespace* `::` *identifier*

You can read about it here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/scope-resolution-operator?view=vs-2017

Comment: Nothing wrong with chaining them either: `myNamespace::myClass::myMember` or `::std::cout`.

Answer (score 11):

One use for the 'Unary Scope Resolution Operator' or 'Colon Colon Operator' is for local and global variable selection of identical names:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    
    int variable = 20;
    
    int main()
    {
    float variable = 30;
    
    cout << "This is local to the main function: " << variable << endl;
    cout << "This is global to the main function: " << ::variable << endl;
    
    return 0;
    }
```

The resulting output would be:

> This is local to the main function: 30
>
> This is global to the main function: 20

Other uses could be: Defining a function from outside of a class, to access a static variable within a class or to use multiple inheritance.

Answer (score -1):

look at it is informative [Qualified identifiers

A qualified id-expression is an unqualified id-expression prepended by a scope resolution operator ::, and optionally, a sequence of enumeration, (since C++11)class or namespace names or decltype expressions (since C++11) separated by scope resolution operators. For example, the expression std::string::npos is an expression that names the static member npos in the class string in namespace std. The expression ::tolower names the function tolower in the global namespace. The expression ::std::cout names the global variable cout in namespace std, which is a top-level namespace. The expression boost::signals2::connection names the type connection declared in namespace signals2, which is declared in namespace boost.

The keyword template may appear in qualified identifiers as necessary to disambiguate dependent template names][1](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers)